# PowerShell Export All Active Directory Properties Including Multi-Valued

Tags: csv, powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to backup the properties for a bunch of user accounts in Active Directory.  I have no problem getting all the properties and exporting them to a CSV but all the mulit-valued properties just show as the type.

Without having to use a join on every property that is multi-valued (which is quite a few) does anyone know of a way to export all a users AD properties with their values?

I would use something like this to get all the properties and export them

`Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'DNOFSEARCH' -Properties * | Export-Csv C:\Temp\users.csv -NoTypeInformation`

But again using that would not have actual values for mutli-valued properties (such as MemberOf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have CSV output and not have to address the nested arrays returned the answer is no. `Export-CSV` is not smart enough for that so you would need to use calculated properties `@{Name="MemberOf";Expression={$_.memberof -join ";"}}`.

If you wanted to not have to worry about that then [`Export-Clixml`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849916.aspx) would be the suggestion. It is aware of objects and structure. I just don't know if your next process will be able to handle/parse that data.

Please avoid the use of `-Properties *` I cannot imagine a scenario where you would need to return *all* of an AD objects properties.

Comment: Thanks this answer worked.  It's not that I necessarily want to add all the properties back, it's just easier than trying to determine all the properties I would need to explicitly state.

Comment: @Aaron I see that used so often incorrectly. Good to know you understand.